# Hebbian Learning explanation

Tags: neural-network

http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/INC/l5.pdf

> The neuropsychologist Donald Hebb postulated in 1949 how biological
>   neurons learn:
>
> “When an axon of cell A is near enough to excite a cell B and
>   repeatedly or persistently takes part in firing it, some growth
>   process or metabolic change takes place on one or both cells such that
>   A’s efficiency as one of the cells firing B, is increased.”
>
> In more familiar terminology, that can be stated as the Hebbian
>   Learning rule:
>
> If two neurons on either side of a synapse (connection) are activated
>   simultaneously (i.e. synchronously), then the strength of that synapse
>   is selectively increased.
>
> Mathematically, we can describe Hebbian learning as:
>
> [image]
>
> Here, η is a learning rate coefficient, and x are the outputs of the
>   ith and jth elements.

---

Now, my question is, what do all these descriptions mean?

1. Is Hebbian Learning applicable for single-neuron networks?
2. What does it mean by "two neurons on either side of a synapse"?
3. Why/when would two neurons activate simultaneously?
4. What does they mean by `elements`? Are they Neurons or anything else?
5. **Can you give an example?**

Answer (score 1):

You have two neurons connected with synapse. In this example we assumed neuron activation only 0 or 1. 1 when weighted input cross the threshold and 0 when not. First neuron activate on 1 and when second neuron activated too, the synapse increase, because activation of first neuron caused activation of second neuron.

When second neuron activate and first no, the synapse will stay same/decrease because activation of second neuron has nothing to do with first neuron.

This can be demonstrated by famous example of feeding dog. When master ring the bell he gave his dog a food. He doing this some period of time and when master ring the bell, dog expected the food, so dog associated these two events bell and food.

[image: Change of synapse]

This can't be used with single neuron network.